# java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

When I run this program I get this error . I don't know how to solve . Help me finding it Please.

```
12-02 23:04:34.427: E/JSON Parser(1629): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Code:

```
public class Http
{

public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds
private static HttpClient mHttpClient;
private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {

      if (mHttpClient == null) {
       mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

       final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
       HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
       HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
       ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
      }

      return mHttpClient;
     }


public static JSONArray getJSONArrayFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {
    try {


           HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

           HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

           request.setURI(new URI(url));

           HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        try {
            // Get our response as a String.
            String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());



            // Parse the JSON String into a JSONArray object.
            return JSONArray(jsonString);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

    }



public static JSONArray retrieveJSON(){
    {
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork()                  .penaltyLog().build());

        String getAllFreebiesURL="http://10.0.2.2/football365/cityList.php";
        JSONArray json = null;
        try {
            json = getJSONArrayFromUrl(getAllFreebiesURL);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("JSON",json+"A");
        //JSONArray json1 = new JSONArray(json);
        //json1.put(json);
        /*try {
            System.out.println(json1.get(2));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        return json;
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: did you get the `json` in **log**.

Comment: looks like a character encoding problem

Comment: @user2310289 show what kind of json response you are getting

Comment: @ Tamilan . yes that's the error that i got when i output json in log .

Comment: @user3032822 post your logcat error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try out as below:
You can parse your response as below:

```
    // Get our response as a String.
    String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
   JSONObject m_jobj;
try {
    m_jobj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray m_ja = m_jobj.getJSONArray("cityData");
    for (int i = 0; i < m_ja.length(); i++) 
     {
                 JSONObject m_obj = m_ja.getJSONObject(i);
                  String city=m_obj.getString("cityID");
                  String cityName=m_obj.getString("cityName");
                   //And so on get all the values.
               }
```

Update your `getJSONArrayFromurl()` as below:

```
public static JSONArray getJSONArrayFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {
    try {


           HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

           HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

           request.setURI(new URI(url));

           HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        try {
            // Get our response as a String.
            String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
       JSONObject m_jobj;
    try {
    m_jobj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray m_ja = m_jobj.getJSONArray("cityData");
    /*for (int i = 0; i < m_ja.length(); i++) 
             {
             JSONObject m_obj = m_ja.getJSONObject(i);
                  String city=m_obj.getString("cityID");
                  String cityName=m_obj.getString("cityName");
                   //And so on get all the values.
               }*/


            // Parse the JSON String into a JSONArray object.
            return m_ja;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

    }
```

Comment: I can't use loopin' . Tht's wht my leader said . What i get is only CityID . Could you help me .

Comment: Without looping how will you get all the CityID ?

Comment: tht's wht I said her . But she command me to use something like dictionary Object or sth like that :(

Comment: Its the only possible with the looping only if you want to get all the CityID from your response. Its a common sense man.

Comment: I'm really sorry . Thanks for your patient .

Comment: Don't be sorry. Always happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

change your method to :

```
public static JSONArray getJSONArrayFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {
try {


       HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

       HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

       request.setURI(new URI(url));

       HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    try {
        // Get our response as a String.
        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObject);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.toJSONArray(new JSONArray(names));


        // Parse the JSON String into a JSONArray object.
        return jsonArray;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant cast string to `JsonArray`, First cast it to a `JsonObject`

```
try {
       JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

Then get the `JsonArray` from it

`jObj.getJSONArray(NAME);`

Comment: when i did this , JAva.lang.String cannot be convert to JSonObject. that's the error i got .