# Json Parsing from Url In Android , Not working

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am parsing data from URL , Its Getting below mentioned Error.

**Raw Data is Showing Perfectly from Server.Not able to Split the Data Using Json Parsing**.

Please help me solve this error

**EDIT : 1**

**Json Response from URL**

```
[
    {
        "ID": 4,
        "Name": "Vinoth",
        "Contact": "1111111111",
        "Msg": "1"
    },
    {
        "ID": 5,
        "Name": "Mani",
        "Contact": "22222222",
        "Msg": "1"
    },
    {
        "ID": 6,
        "Name": "Manoj",
        "Contact": "33333333333",
        "Msg": "1"
    }
]
```

**Error :**

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"ID":1,"Name":"Lalita","Contact":"9997162499","Msg":"1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"kumar","Contact":"123456789","Msg":"1"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo.MainActivity$LoadService.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:135)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo.MainActivity$LoadService.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:58)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-11 18:23:27.249 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
12-11 18:23:27.259 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
12-11 18:23:27.259 30195-30195/com.knowledgeflex.restapidemo W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView name1,email,status,face;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button GetServerData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


      name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sname);
       email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
         status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
       face = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fb);

        GetServerData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Server Request URL
                String serverURL = "http://webapp/api/values";

                // Create Object and call AsyncTask execute Method
                new LoadService().execute(serverURL);

            }
        });

    }


    // Class with extends AsyncTask class
    private class LoadService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;
        private final String TAG = null;
        String name = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        TextView uiUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            // UI Element
            uiUpdate.setText("");
            Dialog.setMessage("Loading service..");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                // NOTE: Don't call UI Element here.

                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // Close progress dialog
            Dialog.dismiss();
            Log.e(TAG, "------------------------------------- Output: " + Content);


            try {
                JSONArray jArr=new JSONArray(Content);
                for(int i=0;i<jArr.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject json=jArr.getJSONObject(i);


                    name1.setText(json.getString("Name"));
                    email.setText(json.getString("ID"));
                    status.setText(json.getString("Contact"));
                    face.setText(json.getString("Msg"));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("EXCEPTION   ","");
            }

            uiUpdate.setText("Raw Output : " + Content);
        }



    }


}
```

Comment: you are return JSONArray change to return JSONObject i think solve your problem

Comment: I recommend that you don't parse it yourself. Try using `Gson` to parse your JSON its easier.

Comment: so this code Will not work?

Comment: Try this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: my json response not having any Json Array Name,what to do for that?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164741/get-jsonarray-without-array-name

Comment: your json is having pure array, this is correct form. There is no defect in schema.

Comment: ya, its only pure array.

Comment: try   String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()) and then convert it to array

Comment: @AnoopKanyan i tried,Not working this code.

Comment: Try-Catch block for good approach .Okay You can test this .Avoid `try-catch` for testing case `JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(Content);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

       JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

       System.out.println("ID : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("ID"));
        System.out.println("Name : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("Name"));
       System.out.println("Contact : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("Contact"));
       System.out.println("Msg : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("Msg"));
       
}`

Comment: what is the problem ,if Try catch Using here?

Comment: @Kumar Strange case .Getting `type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya its giving error message like Unhandled  Excepetion in android studio.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i already posted my code.along with Logcat error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97816/discussion-between-intellij-amiya-and-kumar).

Comment: IMO, you can try using `JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(Content.substring(Content.indexOf("["), Content.lastIndexOf("]") + 1));` instead of `JSONArray jArr=new JSONArray(Content);`

Comment: @BNK   It Shows error message like this After Adding your Code-org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 2 of [{\"ID\":1,\"Name\":\"Lalita\",\"Contact\":\"9997162499\",\"Msg\":\"1\"},{\"ID\":2,\"Name\":\"kumar\",\"Contact\":\"123456789\",\"Msg\":\"1\"},{\"ID\":3,\"Name\":\"Swatantra\",\"Contact\":\"987654321\",\"Msg\":\"1\"},{\"ID\":4,\"Name\":\"Vinoth\",\"Contact\":\"1111111111\",\"Msg\":\"1\"},{\"ID\":5,\"Name\":\"Manish\",\"Contact\":\"22222222\",\"Msg\":\"1\"},{\"ID\":6,\"Name\":\"Manoj\",\"Contact\":\"33333333333\",\"Msg\":\"1\"}]

Comment: Please use `Log.i("Output", Content.substring(Content.indexOf("["), Content.lastIndexOf("]") + 1));` and `Log.i("OutputOrg", Content);` then post the results so that I can check. I guess the string responsed from your web service is not a valid JSON

Comment: Your JSON string at your comment above has an invalid character (I don't know what is that) at `"‌​:2`. You can check by copy & paste it into Notepad+ then use left/right arrow to check (you must press the arrow key 3 times at the position between `"‌​` and `:`

Comment: @BNK Output org log message is not Printing. Showing Error Expected literal value at character 2

Comment: Do you mean `Log.i("OutputOrg", Content);` does not print anything?

Comment: @BNK yes , only uiUpdate.setText("Raw Output : " + Content); showing Some text WIthout Parsing Data.but, logcat  Not Printing anything.Showing this Error Expected literal value at character 2 of [{\"ID\":1,\"Name\":\"Lalita\",\"Contact\":\"9997162499\",\"Msg\":\"1\"},{\"ID\"‌​:2,\"Name\":\"kumar\",\"Contact\":\"123456789\",\"Msg\":\"1\"},{\"ID\":3,\"Name\"‌​:\"Swatantra\",\"Contact\":\"987654321\",\"Msg\":\"1\"},{\"ID\":4,\"Name\":\"Vino‌​th\",\"Contact\":\"1111111111\",\"Msg\":\"1\"},{\"ID\":5,\"Name\":\"Manoj\",\"Contact\":\"33‌​333333333\",\"Msg\":\"1\"}]

Comment: You can temporarily comment the line `JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(Content.substring(Content.indexOf("["), Content.lastIndexOf("]") + 1));` and other lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98205/discussion-between-kumar-and-bnk).

Comment: @Kumar : Please check this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/34331994/4018207

Comment: you got the solution @Kumar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per your response is JSONArray and gson library is better to use while json data parsing so use below class to any type of data like that

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ApiData {
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private JsonArray Data;

    public <T> List<T> getData(Class<T> c) {
        Type type = new ListParams(c);
        return new Gson().fromJson(Data, type);
    }

    private class ListParams implements ParameterizedType {

        private Type type;

        private ListParams(Type type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
            return new Type[]{type};
        }

        @Override
        public Type getRawType() {
            return ArrayList.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Type getOwnerType() {
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return super.equals(o);
        }

    }
}
```

Create model class like :

```
public class Model{
   String ID;
   String Name;
   String Contact;
   String msg;
}
```

Now parse your data like:

```
ApiData apiData = new Gson().fromJson(Content, ApiData.class);
Lis<Model> models = apiData.getData(Model.class);
```

Comment: Let me know if you have faced any issue or explanation required

Answer (score 6):

```
 try {
                Object jsonObject = new JSONTokener(Content).nextValue();
                JSONArray jArr=new JSONArray(jsonObject );
                for(int i=0;i<jArr.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject json=jArr.getJSONObject(i);
                    name1.setText(json.getString("Name"));
                    email.setText(json.getString("ID"));
                    status.setText(json.getString("Contact"));
                    face.setText(json.getString("Msg"));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("EXCEPTION   ","");
            }
```

Directly you cannot apply string to array, you should convert string to jsonobject ,then you can do object to array.
Hope you understand

Comment: still there is an issue, please feel free and let me know

Comment: can you post stacktrace?

Comment: i tried Your Code Still remain same.where i am making mistake?

Comment: of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: previous its shown  ERROR as  java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray . Now its Showing java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

Comment: if you can find the solution,please let me know. i strucked this issue last 3 hours.

Comment: hi ,I have updated my answer pls find it...still you are facing any issue pls let me know

Comment: Thanks for your reply,its giving Error message - org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class java.lang.String

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97698/discussion-between-kumar-and-boopathi).

Answer (score 6):

As i have added escaping to your json here only for storing it temporary :

Please check below parsing code and it is working for me :

```
String response = "[\r\n    {\r\n        \"ID\": 4,\r\n        \"Name\": \"Vinoth\",\r\n        \"Contact\": \"1111111111\",\r\n        \"Msg\": \"1\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n        \"ID\": 5,\r\n        \"Name\": \"Mani\",\r\n        \"Contact\": \"22222222\",\r\n        \"Msg\": \"1\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n        \"ID\": 6,\r\n        \"Name\": \"Manoj\",\r\n        \"Contact\": \"33333333333\",\r\n        \"Msg\": \"1\"\r\n    }\r\n]";
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response); // replace response with your response string
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.e("ID", jsonObject.getInt("ID") + "");
                Log.e("Name", jsonObject.getString("Name"));
                Log.e("Contact", jsonObject.getString("Contact"));
                Log.e("Msg", jsonObject.getString("Msg"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Logs I have printed :

> 12-17 15:42:54.459 9064-9064/com.example.testapplication E/ID: 4 12-17
>   15:42:54.459 9064-9064/com.example.testapplication E/Name: Vinoth
>   12-17 15:42:54.459 9064-9064/com.example.testapplication E/Contact:
>   1111111111 12-17 15:42:54.459 9064-9064/com.example.testapplication
>   E/Msg: 1 12-17 15:42:54.459 9064-9064/com.example.testapplication
>   E/ID: 5 12-17 15:42:54.459 9064-9064/com.example.testapplication
>   E/Name: Mani 12-17 15:42:54.459 9064-9064/com.example.testapplication
>   E/Contact: 22222222 12-17 15:42:54.459
>   9064-9064/com.example.testapplication E/Msg: 1 12-17 15:42:54.459
>   9064-9064/com.example.testapplication E/ID: 6 12-17 15:42:54.459
>   9064-9064/com.example.testapplication E/Name: Manoj 12-17 15:42:54.459
>   9064-9064/com.example.testapplication E/Contact: 33333333333 12-17
>   15:42:54.459 9064-9064/com.example.testapplication E/Msg: 1

Thanks ..!

Comment: Again Error org.json.JSONException: Value [{"ID":1,"Name":"Lalita","Contact":"9997162499","Msg":"1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"kumar","Contact":"123456789","Msg":"1"}]of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray error Occurred

Comment: my response is "Content " Only , how can i add Spacing.

Comment: @Kumar : You do not need to add any spacing for example I have added `escaping` and also your code is working fine on my machine..!!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [public JSONArray (String json)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29) says it throws a

> JSONException if the parse fails or doesn't yield a JSONArray.

Maybe he can't handle your response which is quite funny because a simple online json parser can: http://json.parser.online.fr/

As the user "Jelle van Es" mentioned in a previous comment, I would try Gson to do the work. (I would have commented under his comment but I have to few reputation xD)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `getString` on "ID" when you should be using `getInt`. I tested the JSON string you provided in your question. The following code works:

```
String json =
    "[{\"ID\":4,\"Name\":\"Vinoth\",\"Contact\":\"1111111111\",\"Msg\":\"1\"},{\"ID\":5,\"Name\":\"Mani\",\"Contact\":\"22222222\",\"Msg\":\"1\"},{\"ID\":6,\"Name\":\"Manoj\",\"Contact\":\"33333333333\",\"Msg\":\"1\"}]";
try {
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
  for (int i = 0, len = jsonArray.length(); i < len; i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = jsonObject.getInt("ID");
    String name = jsonObject.getString("Name");
    String contact = jsonObject.getString("Contact");
    String msg = jsonObject.getString("Msg");
    System.out.println("id=" + id + ", name='" + name + "\', contact='" + contact + "\', msg='" + msg);
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output from running the above code:

> id=4, name='Vinoth', contact='1111111111', msg='1
>
> id=5, name='Mani', contact='22222222', msg='1
>
> id=6, name='Manoj', contact='33333333333', msg='1

If you are still getting an error, post the stacktrace.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"ID":1,"Name":"Lalita","Contact":"9997162499","Msg":"1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"kumar","Contact":"123456789","Msg":"1"},{"ID":3,"Name":"Swatantra","Contact":"987654321","Msg":"1"},{"ID":4,"Name":"Vinoth","Contact":"1111111111","Msg":"1"},{"ID":5,"Name":"Manish","Contact":"22222222","Msg":"1"},{"ID":6,"Name":"Manoj","Contact":"33333333333","Msg":"1"},{"ID":7,"Name":"This Url Connected With  Azure Database","Contact":"11111","Msg":"1"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)

Comment: same error, i am getting Raw String Output.but not able to parse that values.

Comment: tested in Two Kitkat devices. but still same error.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link[JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342792/java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray)

You should not directly use the response you get after hitting web service.First convert it to string as given in the link and also use getInt() when you are parsing your id

Answer (score 1):

You can Parse your JSON like below.

```
                    try {
                            JSONArray _jArray = new JSONArray("YOUR_RESPONSE");
                            if (_jArray.length()>0){
                                for (int i = 0 ; i < _jArray.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject _jSObject = _jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    int ID = _jSObject.getInt("ID");
                                    String Name = _jSObject.getString("Name");
                                    String Contact = _jSObject.getString("Contact");
                                    String Msg = _jSObject.getString("Msg");
                                    System.out.println("Id : " + ID);
                                    System.out.println("Name : " + Name);
                                    System.out.println("Contact : " + Contact);
                                    System.out.println("Msg : " + Msg);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: still same Exception. after adding this :(

Comment: i am using the String response ,passing inside json array .but still same error.

Comment: You need the getJSONfromURL() method to return a JSONArray, not a JSONObject.

Comment: you should let them know what is the defect in current system then provide your answer

Comment: can you suggest me any ,other solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Best way and very fast parsing of JSON is GSON liabrary 

dependacy for android studio compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' OR you can download jar.

Make DTO names of all strings exactly same json of resonse.


Class ClassDTO{
    String ID;
    String Name;
    String Contact;
    String Msg;

    take gettters & setters

}

Just include this lines in your code.


JSONArray array=new JSONArray(Content);
if (array.length() > 0) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < array.length()) {
        list.add(gson.fromJson(array.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ClassDTO.class));
        i++;
    }    
} else {
    Toast.makeText(JobCardActivity.this, "No response from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for json url hit and parsing of the data i have use this way
First i have created a class for Async request

```
    public class AsyncRequestForActivities extends
    AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

OnAsyncRequestComplete caller;
Context context;

String method = "POST";
List<NameValuePair> parameters = null;
ProgressDialog pDialog = null;
String Progress_msg;

// Three Constructors
public AsyncRequestForActivities(Context a, String m, String Msg,
        List<NameValuePair> p) {
    caller = (OnAsyncRequestComplete) a;
    context = a;
    method = m;
    parameters = p;
    Progress_msg = Msg;
}

public AsyncRequestForActivities(Context a, String m) {
    caller = (OnAsyncRequestComplete) a;
    context = a;
    method = m;

}

public AsyncRequestForActivities(Context a) {
    caller = (OnAsyncRequestComplete) a;
    context = a;
}

// Interface to be implemented by calling activity
public interface OnAsyncRequestComplete {
    public void asyncResponse(String response);
}

public String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    // get url pointing to entry point of API
    String address = urls[0].toString();
    if (method == "POST") {
        return post(address);
    }

    if (method == "GET") {
        return get(address);
    }

    return null;

}

public void onPreExecute() {

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage(Progress_msg); // typically you will
    pDialog.setCancelable(false); // define such
    // strings in a remote file.
    pDialog.show();

}

public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    // you can implement some progressBar and update it in this record
    // setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
}

public void onPostExecute(String response) {

    if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    caller.asyncResponse(response);
}

protected void onCancelled(String response) {

    if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    caller.asyncResponse(response);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private String get(String address) {
    try {

        if (parameters != null) {

            String query = "";
            String EQ = "=";
            String AMP = "&";
            for (NameValuePair param : parameters) {
                query += param.getName() + EQ
                        + URLEncoder.encode(param.getValue()) + AMP;
            }

            if (query != "") {
                address += "?" + query;
            }
        }

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(address);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

        return stringifyResponse(response);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    return null;
}

private String post(String address) {
    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(address);

        if (parameters != null) {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
        }

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        return stringifyResponse(response);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    return null;
}

private String stringifyResponse(HttpResponse response) {
    BufferedReader in;

    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                .getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        in.close();

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

now when you want to get Data you have to implement the interface in your activity

```
    public class SomeClass extends Activity implements OnAsyncRequestComplete{
    // your activity code here

   // some where in class in any function you want
    AsyncRequestForActivities req=new AsyncRequestForActivities(SomeClass.this, MethodType, YourMessage,
        Perameters_in_List<NameValuePareType>);


    req.execute(YourURL);

    }//end of that function
    @Override
    public void asyncResponse(String response) {

    try {

        if (!(response == null)) {
              JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray("response");
                        if (jArray.length()>0){
                            for (int i = 0 ; i < jArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject jSObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                int ID = _jSObject.getInt("ID");
                                String Name = _jSObject.getString("Name");
                                String Contact = jSObject.getString("Contact");
                                String Msg = jSObject.getString("Msg");
                                System.out.println("Id : " + ID);
                                System.out.println("Name : " + Name);
                                System.out.println("Contact : " + Contact);
                                System.out.println("Msg : " + Msg);
                            }


        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: if the problem presist then fist get the response as JSON Object  like :   JSONObject postObject = new JSONObject(response); then get Array from this Object: hope you will find your solution gone